# How to write to a .dat file Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication

Was Assigned to use Matrix Multiplication to find multiple weights. Then write to a .Dat file these weights. Was never taught how to do such a thing. Does anyone have any steps on how to write to a .Dat file?

Comment: Yeah, default Matlab files end in `.mat`. Generally `.dat` denotes arbitrary data. I'd seek clarification on what exactly they're asking for. If no time for clarification, I'd output to any file format you find convenient.

Comment: The important question is what is the data format of the file, not the extension. If you literally just need to save the data to a `.dat` file then you can just use `save('test.dat', 'variable_name')` but I suspect that this is not what you need.